# Any way of merging blobs in opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have this picture below. I want to merge the two blobs together to get the final contour of the human.

[image: Image1]

[image]

I have tried dilation and erosion techniques to get these blobs to join but the contour is preserving.

```py
    img = cv2.imread(folder+i)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
    dil = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=5)
    fin = cv2.erode(dil, kernel, iterations=5)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(fin, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)
    im_floodfill = thresh.copy()
    h, w = thresh.shape[:2]
    mask = np.zeros((h + 2, w + 2), np.uint8)
    cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0, 0), 255);
    im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
    im_out = thresh | im_floodfill_inv

    cv2.imshow("test", im_out)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Out1]

Out1 is outputting what I want but in [image]

case there is some problem.

Is there some other techniques that I can use without distorting the contour.

Comment: You should try to use morphology close operation on the binary image.

Comment: i am doing exactly that by dilating and eroding as it gives more control over morphological close.

Comment: Dilating is not the same as closing

Comment: Man its written in official OpenCV Page: Closing is reverse of Opening, Dilation followed by Erosion. It is useful in closing small holes inside the foreground objects, or small black points on the object.

Comment: Closing the combination of Dilating and Eroding, so it is not the same Dilating

Comment: Try this `kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_CROSS, (1, 25))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use morphology snakes: [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_morphsnakes.html) or [here](https://github.com/pmneila/morphsnakes).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few method you can try

1. As mentioned morphological close should be able to close small gap. But some of the shape content (e.g armpit) will get destroyed. And it wont work well if top and bottom are too far apart.
2. Improve on input segmentation result. This can be done in many ways. Eg. If you have problem with other backgrounds, then use the deep learning semantic model and overlay with the segmentation result. others like shape prior or snake energy model to remove small opening, as i said, there are a lot of method

this 2 iamage shows that semantic model can get pretty good human shape countour. So use it with your previous detection (which i guess its from bgfg model)
[image]
[image]

3 Use other tools to link the body and leg together with automatically. Eg. If bottom block are totally away and you cant use Morph close to link them.  Use sth like principal component analysis on the leg. Then add one block of white on top of the leg part.  Extend the leg to the top.

It is similar to manually added blocked part in GMAPPING grid map to prevent planned path in some area in Robotics.

There is really too many ways to achieve it. Don't be limited to your imagination.